# How to disactivate the last breadcrumb in InertiaJS?

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, breadcrumbs, inertiajs

I am trying to disactivate the last crumb in InertiaJS (Laravel + Vue3) but I think I have an error or something missing somewhere. The error I am getting is the "isLast" is not defined.

isLast: This method simply takes in an index of the crumb array and checks if that crumb is the last one in the list.
selected: This is a simple method that emits an event whenever a crumb is selected. The event is then caught by Example.vue…
Here is the code:

BreadCrumb.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ol class="inline-flex items-center space-x-1 md:space-x-3">
      <li
          v-for="(crumb, ci) in crumbs"
          :key="ci"
        >
        <div class="inline-flex items-center">
          <icon name="arrow"/>
          <Link :href="`/${crumb}`" as="button" type="button" :class="{ disabled: isLast(ci) }" @click="selected(crumb)" class="capitalize" >
            {{ crumb }}
          </Link>
        </div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import Icon from '@/Shared/Icon'

export default {
  components: {
    Icon,
    Link,
  },
  props: {
    crumbs: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    isLast(index) {
      return index === this.crumbs.length - 1;
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Example.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="md:p-12 md:pt-1">
    <breadcrumb class="flex pl-4 mb-12" :crumbs="crumbs" @selected="selected"></breadcrumb>  
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Breadcrumb from '@/Shared/Breadcrumb'

export default {
  components: {
    Breadcrumb,
  },
  return {
      crumbs: ['home','users', 'create'],
    }
  methods: {
    selected(crumb) {
      console.log(crumb);
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend binding the disabled-attribute

```html
<Link ... :disabled="isLast(ci)" >
```